# How to detect a change of directory through the loop of Python's os.walk() method?

Tags: python, directory

How to actually detect the change of directory in os.walk loop?

Here's my code :

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:\Users\myuser\folder"):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".fri")]:
        execute_file(dirpath, filename)
```

Can i write something like this?

```
if dirpath == os.walk(r"C:\Users\myuser\folder")[(dirpath, dirnames, filenames).index+1]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so unclear that I should probably vote to close it instead but anyway, let's just concentrate on the main subject line:

> How to actually detect the change of directory in os.walk loop?

Quite simply: store the previous directory in a variable and test against this variable.

```
prev_dir = None

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:\Users\myuser\folder"):
    # special case for the firsy iteration
    if prev_dir is None:
        prev_dir = dirpath

    # common case: is this a new dir ?
    if prev_dir != dirpath:
        print("directory changed from {} to {}".format(prev_dir, dirpath)
        prev_dir = dirpath
```

Unrelated, but this:

```
for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".fri")]:
    execute_file(dirpath, filename)
```

is a rather pointless. Since you're going to have a plain for loop, just put the test in it:

```
for filename in filenames:
    if f.endswith(".fri"):
        execute_file(dirpath, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to detect.
Each iteration through os.walk() is a changed base directory (dirpath changed)

Just try calling

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:\Users\myuser\folder"):
    print(dirpath)
```

and you will see, that dirpath is always different.

Concerning the second question:

The answer is no.
`os.walk()` is a generator and can therefore not be indexed.

But perhaps you can explain what the code is supposed to do and we can find a way to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You may add another for loop in between the other two to check which directory you are in

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"C:\Users\myuser\folder"):
    for dir in dirnames:
        if dir != "folder":
            continue
        for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".fri")]:
            execute_file(dirpath, filename)
```